# Javascript inArray not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have using html file upload control in `asp .net`, try to restrict the file extension in script block. For fixed file extensions `(.pdf,.txt,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.eml,.msg)` in `inArray` it has working fine. When checking the same in array variable `(array1)` it is not working.

Code :

```
var AllowedFileExtensions = ".pdf,.txt,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.eml,.msg";
var array1 = new Array();
array1 = AllowedFileExtensions.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = "'" + array1[i] + "'";
}

var ext = $('#fileDocUpload').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
ext = '.' + ext;

alert([array1]); // it throws the text = '.pdf','.txt','.doc','.docx','.xls','.xlsx','.eml','.msg'
alert(ext); // .pdf
```

This Code worked fine :

```
If ($.inArray(ext, ['.pdf','.txt','.doc','.docx','.xls','.xlsx','.eml','.msg']) == -1) {
if ($.inArray(ext.toString, array1) == -1) {
     alert('invalid extension!');
     return false 
}
```

This Code not worked :

```
if ($.inArray(ext.toString, array1) == -1) {
     alert('invalid extension!');
     return false 
}
```

Comment: You don't need `array1[i] = "'" + array1[i] + "'"`, You can simply use `AllowedFileExtensions.split(",").indexOf(ext.toString) == -1`

Comment: @Satpal, i already try this but not worked, so only i have try to add quotes between those..

Comment: @bgs: what is the value of `ext.toString`?

Comment: ext.toString = .pdf @MilindAnantwar

Comment: @bgs: should work then http://jsfiddle.net/qey9bLb3/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, when changing the code ext.toString to ext , working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are modifying the array1 to put extra quotes in each value. which modifies the array to:

```
["'.pdf'", "'.txt'", "'.doc'", "'.docx'", "'.xls'", "'.xlsx'", "'.eml'", "'.msg'"]
```

You dont need to put the value in quotes. `.split()` will handle it when converting the values to array here:

```
var array1 = AllowedFileExtensions.split(",");
if ($.inArray(ext.toString, array1) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
    return false 
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity: does $.inArray() handle cases? If one uploads a file ending with .PDF, would it get rejected?

Comment: yes it will be rejected. you need to only get the extension from url and then use it in `inArray`

Comment: Never mind, it is correct in the actual question. Just not visible in your answer. All good :)